# Form not inputting in database using PDO prepare and INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For some reason when I fill in my basic registration form nothing goes wrong, it says everything is completed, but when I go take a look in my database nothing is saved in there.

This is my form:

```
<form method="post">
        <p id="registryinput">Voornaam:<input name="voornaam" type="text"></p><br>
        <p id="registryinput">Tussenvoegsels:<input name="tussenvoegsel" type="text"></p><br>
        <p id="registryinput">Achternaam:<input name="achternaam" type="text"></p><br>
        <p id="registryinput">E-mail:<input name="email" type="text"></p><br>
        <p id="registryinput">Wachtwoord:<input name="wachtwoord" type="password"></p><br>
        <p id="registryinput">Herhaal wachtwoord:<input name="herhaalwachtwoord" type="password"></p><br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Registreren">
    </form>
```

This is the db connection:

```
<?php
    $host_name = "localhost";
    $database = "login";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host_name.";dbname=".$database,$username,$password);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: ".$e->getMessage()."<br/>";
        die();
    }   
?>
```

This is the code that I use to upload to the database:

```
<?php
        include("connect.php");

        $voornaam = @$_POST["voornaam"];
        $tussenvoegsel = @$_POST["tussenvoegsel"];
        $achternaam = @$_POST["achternaam"];
        $email = @$_POST["email"];
        $wachtwoord = @$_POST["wachtwoord"];
        $herhaalwachtwoord = @$_POST["herhaalwachtwoord"];
        $submit = @$_POST["submit"];
        $encpassword = md5($password);

        if($submit){
            if($voornaam==true){
                if($achternaam==true){
                    if($email==true){
                        if($wachtwoord==true){
                            if($herhaalwachtwoord==true){
                                if($wachtwoord==$herhaalwachtwoord){
                                    if(strlen($voornaam)<50){
                                        if(strlen($tussenvoegsel)<50){
                                            if(strlen($achternaam)<50){
                                                if(strlen($email)<50){
                                                    if(strlen($wachtwoord)<50){
                                                        $q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 'userinfo' ('voornaam','tussenvoegsel','achternaam','email','wachtwoord') VALUES (':voornaam',':tussenvoegsel',':achternaam',':email',':wachtwoord')");
                                                        $q->execute(array(':voornaam'=>$voornaam,':tussenvoegsel'=>$tussenvoegsel,':achternaam'=>$achternaam,':email'=>$email,':wachtwoord'=>$wachtwoord));
                                                        echo "Registratie succesvol!";
                                                    } else {
                                                        echo "Wachtwoord langer dan 50 karakters.";
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    echo "E-mail langer dan 50 karakters.";
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                echo "Achternaam langer dan 50 karakters.";
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            echo "Tussenvoegsel langer dan 50 karakters.";
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        echo "Voornaam langer dan 50 karakters.";
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    echo "Wachtwoorden zijn niet gelijk.";
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo "Herhaal uw wachtwoord.";
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "Geen wachtwoord ingevuld.";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "Geen e-mail ingevuld.";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Geen achternaam ingevuld.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Geen voornaam ingevuld.";
            }
        }   
    ?>
```

My main concern is if this part is right:

```
$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 'userinfo' ('voornaam','tussenvoegsel','achternaam','email','wachtwoord') VALUES (':voornaam',':tussenvoegsel',':achternaam',':email',':wachtwoord')");
$q>execute(array(':voornaam'=>$voornaam,':tussenvoegsel'=>$tussenvoegsel,':achternaam'=>$achternaam,':email'=>$email,':wachtwoord'=>$wachtwoord));
```

Don't mind all the value names I'm dutch so all the text on the page is dutch

I actually worked along a little bit more and dropped on another problem, my second objective was to make a login form using the SELECT * option and i got it working. Only problem is for username i am using E-mail but when it tries to call the value of E-mail (for example Thodor20@gmail.com) it comes up with this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com = 'admin'' at line 1' in C:\wamp\www\PWS\index.php on line 15
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com = 'admin'' at line 1 in C:\wamp\www\PWS\index.php on line 15

I know why this isn't working though it recognizes the E-mail as a value Thodor20@gmail.com where @gmail.com is seperated because of the @.
So how can I change the existing code:

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");

    $logemail = @$_POST['email'];
    $logww = @$_POST['wachtwoord'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $q2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE $logemail = '$logww'");
        $q2->execute(array(':email'=>$logemail,':wachtwoord'=>$logww));
        echo "Login succesvol!";
    }
?>
```

And the form:

```
<form method="post">
    E-mail:<input type="text" name="email"><br>
    Wachtwoord:<input type="password" name="wachtwoord"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Inloggen"><br>
</form>
```

So it will accept Thodor20@gmail.com as 1 full value and not in parts?

Comment: Is it really necessary to nest every `if` statement inside another?

Comment: my god, it looks like a weird pyramid waiting to fall down, why can't you just combine those

Comment: I know it isn't the most effective but I like it this way since I can find quicker where to look

Comment: also the reason i put all the code in this pyramid form is so it well check 1 by 1 if everything is filled in and it won't continue if a field is not filled in and therefore can say which field is not filled in

Comment: I don't know where you came up with this pattern, but what you've created here is **highly unmaintainable**. Your use of `@$_POST` is a form of [cargo-cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), it's completely unnecessary, and comparing things to `true` inside a logical block like `if` is redundant. You really should be using a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) to give your code some structure and meaning. This is completely off the rails.

Comment: Well this is my assignment for secondary school, I'm trying to make  a sort of online diary, the reason I'm writing it like this is because it doesn't have to be fancy coding, my teacher just wants the website working :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using quotes around your table, columns and placeholders, remove them.

Those are not the right [**identifiers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

```
INSERT INTO userinfo (voornaam,tussenvoegsel,achternaam,email,wachtwoord)   
VALUES (:voornaam,:tussenvoegsel,:achternaam,:email,:wachtwoord)
```

having used

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

right after the connection is opened, would have signaled the error.

This `$q>execute` is missing a `-` so change it to `$q->execute` the arrow operator is malformed. (although you seem to have it in your full body of code), it was worth mentioning just in case.

---

I also noticed you are using `if($submit){` it's usually best using

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}
```

Using `@` symbols for `@$_POST` suppresses [**errors**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). It's best not to use them.

---

**Password storage**

You are using [**MD5**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) for password storage `md5($password)`.
This is no longer considered safe to use anymore.

I recommed you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @Ghost Seems like the OP had it right in the big body of code `$q->execute(array(` was only under that, where is saying *"My main concern is if this part is right:"* but thanks for that though. It shows you pay attention to detail ;)

Comment: to be honest, i didn't see that one the first skim, the one that struck me was that pyramid if. so much for [If you need more than 3 levels of indentation, you're screwed?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/52685/if-you-need-more-than-3-levels-of-indentation-youre-screwed)

Comment: @Ghost True. OP says can find stuff quicker. Kind of a neat effect though lol

Comment: but when I take all the @ off I get an error for all of them saying undefined index

Comment: no it doesn't matter whether i put them in or not after i tried all your changes i keep getting a fatal error:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'field list'' in C:\wamp\www\PWS\register.php on line 28
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'field list' in C:\wamp\www\PWS\register.php on line 28

Comment: @user3307080 If it still doesn't work, then I suggest either you remove `if($voornaam==true)` and similar ones (unless they worked for you before moving over to PDO), or changing them to `if(isset($_POST["voornaam"]))` or `if(!empty($_POST["voornaam"]))` etc. that's the only reason why I think you would get the `Undefined index...` warnings.

Comment: @user3307080 Do you not have an `email` column in your table? It's in your query.

Comment: oh fred that could be it the column is defined as e-mail

Comment: @user3307080 Exactly. If your column is called `e-mail` then that would do it. If you want to retain that name, you will need to wrap it in backticks `\`` in the query, or change the column name to `email` which may be the best thing to do.

Comment: the reason i did this though the variable name in the beginning can't be e-mail since only $e will be considered a name and it won't use -mail in the name and that would return an error

Comment: @user3307080 I understand. So, your column in DB is named `e-mail`, correct? If it is, just rename it to `email` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Fred it worked, got it working now and my first registry is displaying in the table, you're great.

Answer (score 1):

No, the SQL text is not correct.  Identifiers are not enclosed in single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO 'userinfo' ('voornaam','tussenvoegsel'
            ^        ^  ^        ^ ^             ^
```

(When MySQL sees the single quotes, it's seeing a string literal, not a table name or column name.)

The fix is to remove all those single quotes from your SQL text.

If an identifier needs to be escaped, it can be enclosed in backtick characters.  (The funky back quote character, inconveniently located on the key to the left of the "1" key on my keyboard.

```
INSERT INTO `userinfo` (`voornaam`,`tussenvoegsel`
```